# Implement Display on all simple Enums?

Tags: rust

I've got a bunch of long but simple Enums floating around. These often have an unwieldy number of fields, and the `strum` crate has been useful in managing them.

I had the idea that it would be nice to implement `Display` for all of these by backing it with the derived `Debug` behavior. This works nicely on a case-by-case basis, but I would like to do it for everything I've derived EnumIter for.

The notion of implementing a trait for all such enums seems to work, as the following code works fine:

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use strum::IntoEnumIterator;
use strum_macros::EnumIter;
pub trait AllEnum : Sized{
    fn all_enum() -> Vec<Self>;
 }
impl<T> AllEnum for T where T : IntoEnumIterator{
    fn all_enum() -> Vec<Self> {
        Self::iter().collect()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, EnumIter)]
enum Example{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}
impl Display for Example{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}
pub fn test() {
    let stuff = Example::all_enum();
    println!("Core display works! {}, {}, {}", stuff[0], stuff[1], stuff[2]);
}
//OUTPUT: Core display works! First, Second, Third
```

But note that I had to implement `Display` on `Example`, despite nothing in the code of that implementation being specific to Example.

I'm trying to make a blanket implementation, but apparently that's disallowed for reasons I'm not clear on:

```
impl<T> Display for T where T : IntoEnumIterator{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}
```

fails with

```
type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

From what I can tell there's no great workaround for the blanket implementation of a foreign trait thing, but is there another way to get the same behavior?

Comment: What's so hard in adding a `strum::Display` in the derive list for every enum?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I didn't know it existed (also looking for it, I think it's actually `strum_macros::Display`, right?). That works for my use case, but I'm curious if there's a deeper solution (one I can apply in general, rather than "Hope a crate has a solution for me").

Comment: In general, there is not a solution for this. Traits like `Display` are meant to be implemented manually because there is not an obvious default implementation.

Comment: `strum` reexports `strum_macros`, so both work.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I get errors if I try to refer to `Display` thru `strum` rather than `strum_macros`.

Comment: You need to enable the `derive` feature.